# Try to making popup form only show one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, popup

I'm new to javascript.
Below is my popup form code,
try to find a way to make popup form only show one time. 
Looking for a solution.
Can someone help me?

Here is my form code:

```
<div id="bkgOverlay" class="backgroundOverlay"></div>

<div id="delayedPopup" class="delayedPopupWindow">

  </div>
  <!-- Begin Pop-up Signup Form -->
  <div id="mc_embed_signup">

    <form action="# " method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">

        <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn btn-default">
      </div>
</form>
  </div>
  <!-- End Signup Form -->
</div>
```

I've included these in the header of the page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Then follows the message using a jQuery popup. Here it is:

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            //Fade in delay for the background overlay (control timing here)
            $("#bkgOverlay").delay(9800).fadeIn(400);
          //Fade in delay for the popup (control timing here)

            $("#delayedPopup").delay(10000).fadeIn(400);

            //Hide dialouge and background when the user clicks the close button
            $("#btnClose,.backgroundOverlay").click(function (e)
            {
                HideDialog();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //Controls how the modal popup is closed with the close button
        function HideDialog()
        {
            $("#bkgOverlay").fadeOut(400);
            $("#delayedPopup").fadeOut(300);
        }
            </script>
```

Comment: if my answer helped you please mark as "accepted" and vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- keep track of the fact you have shown the dialog to this user before
- isolate the show function
- use a cookie to persist the event of showing

can't guarantee it works 100% because i don't have the time now, but you can surely get started with this.

therefore I re-wrote the code above:

```
<script>
    var didShowOnce = false;

    var canShowDialog = function () {
        // try to read cookie
        var ckvalue = $.cookie('dialog-shown');
        if (typeof ckvalue !== 'undefined' && ckvalue != null) {
            didShowOnce = ckvalue == '1';
        }
        // write cookie to make sure it sticks
        $.cookie('dialog-shown', didShowOnce ? '1' : '0', { expires: 365, path: '/' });

        return !didShowOnce;
    };


    $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowDialog();
    });


    var ShowDialog = function () {

        if (canShowDialog()) {

            $.cookie('dialog-shown', '1', { expires: 365, path: '/' });

            //Fade in delay for the background overlay (control timing here)
            $("#bkgOverlay").delay(9800).fadeIn(400);
            //Fade in delay for the popup (control timing here)

            $("#delayedPopup").delay(10000).fadeIn(400);

            //Hide dialouge and background when the user clicks the close button
            $("#btnClose,.backgroundOverlay").click(function (e)
            {
                HideDialog();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }

    var HideDialog = function () {
        $("#bkgOverlay").fadeOut(400);
        $("#delayedPopup").fadeOut(300);
    }
</script>
```